# HTML+Javascript: How can I Load Data in Div via Class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just want to ask if it is possible to separate my View (HTML & CSS files) in such a controller like JavascriptCode/AJAX, and when the time the page was loaded only the controller will bind the data to that specific element like DIV via its class.

is it possible?

please give me some reference on how to do it.

Comment: yes it is possible.share some code first.

Comment: sorry but i don't have any code. I just came to an idea that if one person created the layout(html & css) and the one created the backend at both the same time, it will lessen the development period of the project. and only the class or id of an element will be the "glue" to combine those. please help me Milind Anantwar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cand add data to a Div using:

```
$('.ClassName').html(data); // will override all content
```

or

```
$('.ClassName').append(data); // will append content to the actual content of the DIV
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your data to a DIV using jQuery like this:

```
$('.yourClassName').html(yourData);
```

if you share your code, it would be helpful in providing exact answer :)

Comment: thank you for your answer. i really appreciated it Saeedses.. =)